# how to call both php function and javascript function for a click of a single button?

Tags: php

For the click of a button I have Validate the page through the Javascript and I have compare the data selected in the dropdown list with the database, that too before the page submit to the server.

So I am planning to call two functions (Javascript and php function) for click of a single button.

Is my approach (solution) is right or is there any other ways.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the data selected in the dropdown list with the database through ajax and if matched then you can submit the form.

Comment: If he selects the dropdownlist then itself I can compare with the database right. Please could you provide me the code for that.

Comment: @iNDU: Nope, You have to do it by yourself and come back with specific problem

Answer (score 0):

To call the php function on the same page, you will need to work with AJAX, as it is a server-side script.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, its a jQuery Ajax code.

test.php is the php page where matching will be done with the database.

1. Receive selectedData as post variable in test.php
2. Query ur database with selectedData value to match.
3. If match found return "matched" otherwise "not matched".

`$.post("test.php", 
  { 
     selectedData: $("#yourdropdownid option:selected").val() 
  },
   function(data) {
     if(data=="matched") {
    // submit the form here
     } else {
    // alert user that seleted value is not in database
     }

   });`

Comment: I didn't understand your 1st point, that is Receive selectedData as post variable in test.php. what it means

Comment: It means that we are sending the selected value of dropdown as "selectedData = valueofdropdown" to test.php and you have to receive this as $selected_value = $_POST['selectedData'];